# How to convert timestamp in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timestamp

Im currently displaying a timestamp attached to each message sent in a message App Im building. However every stack overflow question I found on converting timestamps has to do with angular or native and I am trying to do this in react. Was wondering what code would I use to display something like (ex: 2/8/2018 11:04am || or something similar).

The current .push to the message array im using is:

```
this.messagesRef.push(
    {
        content: this.state.userMsg,
        roomId: this.props.activeRoom.key,
        username: (this.props.user ? this.props.user.displayName : 'guest'),
        sentAt: this.props.firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    }
);
```

My git hub push for this was [(Git Link)](https://github.com/DravionV/bloc-chat-react/commit/03673a3de77f302113a3ffcb2544deb8b4c850e7)

Comment: Can you not use something like `date-fns` to transform the timestamp to something more readable like what you have above?

Comment: Not sure how I would implement date-fns to my doc?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

If you have the timestamp number you can get it formatted as you asked like this:

```js
const timestamp = Date.now(); // This would be the timestamp you want to format

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(timestamp));
```

If you want the date with one number instead of two (2/8/2018 vs 02/08/2018) just change the format from '2-digit' to 'numeric' on the corresponding time unit.

Answer (score 8):

You can define method like this

```js
const dateString = '2020-05-14T04:00:00Z'

const formatDate = (dateString) => {
  const options = { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric"}
  return new Date(dateString).toLocaleDateString(undefined, options)
}

console.log(formatDate(dateString))
```

if you want to read detail about this check this post https://css-tricks.com/how-to-convert-a-date-string-into-a-human-readable-format/

#### Update

To get eg. **9PM or 9AM** format add following code inside `options`

```
hour: 'numeric', hour12: true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to avoid handling timestamp with dedicated method/code, you could use directly an existing react component for that.

Fo example you could pick [react-simple-timestamp-to-date](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-timestamp-to-date) and apply this in your render method:

```
import SimpleDateTime  from 'react-simple-timestamp-to-date';

(...)
  render() {
    return (
      <SimpleDateTime dateFormat="DMY" dateSeparator="/"  timeSeparator=":">{this.state.myTimestamp}</SimpleDateTime>
    );
  }
```